# No signature token Java CXF Client

Tags: java, web-services, wcf, cxf, cxf-codegen-plugin

I'm trying to buil a Java client with Apache-CXF-2.7.11 that communicates with .NET WCF services.

My Java client code is following, the client were autogenerating whith the IDE, only the credentials i've copied  from the CXF docs.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws java.lang.Exception {
    URL wsdlURL = Reportes.WSDL_LOCATION;
    if (args.length > 0 && args[0] != null && !"".equals(args[0])) { 
        File wsdlFile = new File(args[0]);
        try {
            if (wsdlFile.exists()) {
                wsdlURL = wsdlFile.toURI().toURL();
            } else {
                wsdlURL = new URL(args[0]);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Reportes ss = new Reportes(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
    IReportes port = ss.getWSHttpBindingIReportes();

    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
    Endpoint cxfEndpoint = client.getEndpoint();

    Map ctx = ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext();
    ctx.put("ws-security.username", "username");
    ctx.put("ws-security.password", "password");

    WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(ctx);
    cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);

    {
    System.out.println("Invoking programaProveedores...");
    java.lang.String _programaProveedores_idBeneficiario = "";
    com.wsclient.ArrayOfProgramaProveedor _programaProveedores__return = port.programaProveedores(_programaProveedores_idBeneficiario);
    System.out.println("programaProveedores.result=" + _programaProveedores__return);


    }
System.exit(0);
}
```

An exception is the result:

```
Advertencia: Interceptor for {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/wsdl}SecurityTokenService#{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/wsdl}RequestSecurityToken has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No signature token
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.SymmetricBindingHandler.doSignBeforeEncrypt(SymmetricBindingHandler.java:398)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.SymmetricBindingHandler.handleBinding(SymmetricBindingHandler.java:124)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor$PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor.java:173)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor$PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor.java:90)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:570)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:479)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:382)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:335)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.AbstractSTSClient.issue(AbstractSTSClient.java:782)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.STSClient.requestSecurityToken(STSClient.java:62)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.STSClient.requestSecurityToken(STSClient.java:56)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.STSClient.requestSecurityToken(STSClient.java:52)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.interceptors.SecureConversationOutInterceptor.issueToken(SecureConversationOutInterceptor.java:167)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.interceptors.SecureConversationOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SecureConversationOutInterceptor.java:69)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.interceptors.SecureConversationOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SecureConversationOutInterceptor.java:44)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:570)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:479)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:382)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:335)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:135)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.programaProveedores(Unknown Source)
at com.wsclient.IReportes_WSHttpBindingIReportes_Client.main(IReportes_WSHttpBindingIReportes_Client.java:76)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: No signature token
```

There's other way to set username token?

PD Sorry for my english...

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem, what i'm trying to do is to import a WCF-created WSDL from a Java client, originally i use [wsimport](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsimport-tool-example/), after that i use Metro 2.3.0 and i get the following error:

```
Advertencia: SP0100: Policy assertion Assertion[com.sun.xml.ws.policy.sourcemodel.DefaultPolicyAssertionCreator$DefaultPolicyAssertion] {
assertion data {
    namespace = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy'
    prefix = 'mssp'
    local name = 'SslContextToken'
    value = 'null'
    optional = 'false'
    ignorable = 'false'
    attributes {
        name = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy:IncludeToken', value = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient'
    }
}
no parameters
nested policy {
    namespace version = 'v1_5'
    id = 'null'
    name = 'null'
    vocabulary {
        1. entry = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy:RequireDerivedKeys'
    }
    assertion set {
        Assertion[com.sun.xml.ws.policy.sourcemodel.DefaultPolicyAssertionCreator$DefaultPolicyAssertion] {
            assertion data {
                namespace = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy'
                prefix = 'sp'
                local name = 'RequireDerivedKeys'
                value = 'null'
                optional = 'false'
                ignorable = 'false'
                no attributes
            }
            no parameters
            no nested policy
        }
    }
}
} is not supported under Token assertion.
```

The reason is that WCF WS-Policy was contaning this section:

```
<mssp:SslContextToken 
sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient" xmlns:mssp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
  <wsp:Policy>
    <sp:RequireDerivedKeys/>
  </wsp:Policy>
</mssp:SslContextToken>
```

This means that your WCF service uses X.509 certificates negotiation. In such a scenario, clients use the server X.509 certificate for encryption. The unique here is that clients are not required to have this certificate out of band (as in most cases), rather they get this certificate using a SOAP-level negotiation. This is implemented as an extension over WS-Trust. While this is not strictly a proprietary Microsoft solution, Microsoft was the only one to implement it so far. In short - **X.509 negotiation (SslContextToken) is not interoperable**.To turn it off either update your WsHttpBinding configuration:

```
<bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding>
            <security mode="Message">
                <message clientCredentialType="None" negotiateServiceCredential="false" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Or choose the correct scenario in your CustomBinding:

```
<security authenticationMode="AnonymousForCertificate">
   <secureConversationBootstrap />
</security>
```

You can also use the equivalent cases for username authentication. Note that any clients (including WCF ones) will now need to have the service certificates defined out of band.

The reference to this problem was http://webservices20.blogspot.mx/2008/10/interoperability-gotcha-sslcontexttoken.html