# 'javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: No signature token' Apache CXF

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, ws-security

I'm trying to develop webservice client using Apache CXF that will connect to WCF service that uses WS-Security and X509 certificate, that is placed in WSDL file. I'm working with stubs generated by wsdl2java utility. Unfortunately, after trying numberous solutions and each return following error, when i call webmethod: `javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: No signature token` and the cause of exceptions is `org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: No signature token`

Solution 1:

```
Service srv = new Service();
IService isrv = srv.getWSHttpBindingIService();
Map ctx = ((BindingProvider)srv.getPort(IService.class)).getRequestContext();
ctx.put("ws-security.username", username);
ctx.put("ws-security.password", password);
org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(isrv);
org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Endpoint cxfEndpoint  = client.getEndpoint();
WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(ctx);
cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);
isrv.pingService();
```

Solution 2:

```
Service srv = new Service();
IService isrv = srv.getWSHttpBindingIService();
org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(isrv);
org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Endpoint cxfEndpoint  = client.getEndpoint();java.util.HashMap<String, Object> outProps = new java.util.HashMap<String, Object>();
outProps.put("action", "UsernameToken Timestamp");
outProps.put(username , password);
outProps.put("passwordCallbackClass", "controllers.UTPasswordCallback");
WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps);
cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);
isrv.pingService();
```

Solution 3:

```
Service srv = new Service();
IService isrv = srv.getWSHttpBindingIService();
org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(isrv); Bus bus = ((EndpointImpl) client.getEndpoint()).getBus();
STSClient stsClient = new STSClient(bus);
stsClient.setSendRenewing(false);
Map<String, Object> ctx = ((BindingProvider) isrv).getRequestContext();
ctx.put("ws-security.username", username);
ctx.put("ws-security.password", password);
ctx.put("ws-security.encryption.properties", "clientTruststore.properties");
ctx.put("ws-security.encryption.username", "token-encryption"); 
ctx.put("ws-security.signature.properties", "clientTruststore.properties");
ctx.put("ws-security.signature.username", "token-signing");
ctx.put("ws-security.is-bsp-compliant", "false");
ctx.put("ws-security.sts.client", stsClient);
WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(ctx);
org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Endpoint cxfEndpoint  = client.getEndpoint();
cxfEndpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);
isrv.pingService();
```

Each gives the same result, here's the stack trace:
`javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: No signature token
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:161)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy62.pingService(Unknown Source)
    at controllers.Application.index(Application.java:92)
    at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Routes.scala:90)
    at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Routes.scala:90)
    at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$4.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:136)
    at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$14$$anon$3$$anon$1.invocation(HandlerInvoker.scala:127)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:70)
    at play.http.DefaultHttpRequestHandler$1.call(DefaultHttpRequestHandler.java:20)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$7.apply(JavaAction.scala:94)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$7.apply(JavaAction.scala:94)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:40)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:70)
    at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext.execute(HttpExecutionContext.scala:32)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$.apply(Future.scala:31)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$.apply(Future.scala:492)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction.apply(JavaAction.scala:94)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:105)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:105)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:104)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:103)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:103)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:96)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:524)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:524)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:560)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:560)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Iteratee.scala:536)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Iteratee.scala:536)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: No signature token
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AbstractCommonBindingHandler.unassertPolicy(AbstractCommonBindingHandler.java:92)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.SymmetricBindingHandler.doSignBeforeEncrypt(SymmetricBindingHandler.java:300)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.SymmetricBindingHandler.handleBinding(SymmetricBindingHandler.java:126)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor$PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessageInternal(PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor.java:187)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor$PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor$PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:514)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:423)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:324)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:277)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.AbstractSTSClient.issue(AbstractSTSClient.java:851)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.STSClient.requestSecurityToken(STSClient.java:61)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.STSClient.requestSecurityToken(STSClient.java:55)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.trust.STSClient.requestSecurityToken(STSClient.java:51)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.interceptors.SecureConversationOutInterceptor.issueToken(SecureConversationOutInterceptor.java:198)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.interceptors.SecureConversationOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SecureConversationOutInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.policy.interceptors.SecureConversationOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SecureConversationOutInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:514)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:423)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:324)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:277)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:139)
    ... 40 more`

If anyone can help me to overcome this error, or provide another solution how to deal with WS-Security in CXF i will be gratful. Thanks!

Edit:
Here's the security policy:

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_IService_policy">
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
<wsp:All>
<sp:SymmetricBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:ProtectionToken>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:SecureConversationToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:RequireDerivedKeys/>
<sp:BootstrapPolicy>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:SignedParts>
<sp:Body/>
<sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
</sp:SignedParts>
<sp:EncryptedParts>
<sp:Body/>
</sp:EncryptedParts>
<sp:SymmetricBinding>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:ProtectionToken>
<wsp:Policy>
<mssp:SslContextToken xmlns:mssp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy" sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:RequireDerivedKeys/>
</wsp:Policy>
</mssp:SslContextToken>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:ProtectionToken>
<sp:AlgorithmSuite>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:Basic256/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:AlgorithmSuite>
<sp:Layout>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:Strict/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:Layout>
<sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
<sp:EncryptSignature/>
<sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:SymmetricBinding>
<sp:SignedSupportingTokens>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:WssUsernameToken10/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:UsernameToken>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:SignedSupportingTokens>
<sp:Wss11>
<wsp:Policy/>
</sp:Wss11>
<sp:Trust10>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:MustSupportIssuedTokens/>
<sp:RequireClientEntropy/>
<sp:RequireServerEntropy/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:Trust10>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:BootstrapPolicy>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:SecureConversationToken>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:ProtectionToken>
<sp:AlgorithmSuite>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:Basic256/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:AlgorithmSuite>
<sp:Layout>
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:Strict/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:Layout>
<sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
<sp:EncryptSignature/>
<sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:SymmetricBinding>
<sp:Wss11 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<wsp:Policy/>
</sp:Wss11>
<sp:Trust10 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<wsp:Policy>
<sp:MustSupportIssuedTokens/>
<sp:RequireClientEntropy/>
<sp:RequireServerEntropy/>
</wsp:Policy>
</sp:Trust10>
<wsaw:UsingAddressing/>
</wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_IService_PingService_Input_policy">
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
<wsp:All>
<sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<sp:Body/>
<sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
</sp:SignedParts>
<sp:EncryptedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<sp:Body/>
</sp:EncryptedParts>
</wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_IService_PingService_output_policy">
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
<wsp:All>
<sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<sp:Body/>
<sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
</sp:SignedParts>
<sp:EncryptedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<sp:Body/>
</sp:EncryptedParts>
</wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_IService_PingDatabase_Input_policy">
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
<wsp:All>
<sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<sp:Body/>
<sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
</sp:SignedParts>
<sp:EncryptedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<sp:Body/>
</sp:EncryptedParts>
</wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_IService_PingDatabase_output_policy">
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
<wsp:All>
<sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<sp:Body/>
<sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
</sp:SignedParts>
<sp:EncryptedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<sp:Body/>
</sp:EncryptedParts>
</wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_IService_GetUserList_Input_policy">
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
<wsp:All>
<sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<sp:Body/>
<sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
</sp:SignedParts>
<sp:EncryptedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<sp:Body/>
</sp:EncryptedParts>
</wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_IService_GetUserList_output_policy">
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
<wsp:All>
<sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<sp:Body/>
<sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
</sp:SignedParts>
<sp:EncryptedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<sp:Body/>
</sp:EncryptedParts>
</wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_IService_CheckUserPermission_Input_policy">
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
<wsp:All>
<sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<sp:Body/>
<sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
</sp:SignedParts>
<sp:EncryptedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<sp:Body/>
</sp:EncryptedParts>
</wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_IService_CheckUserPermission_output_policy">
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
<wsp:All>
<sp:SignedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<sp:Body/>
<sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
<sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"/>
</sp:SignedParts>
<sp:EncryptedParts xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
<sp:Body/>
</sp:EncryptedParts>
</wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

Comment: What does the security policy of the service look like?

Comment: Well, WCF is a little "proprietary", as stated in the answer to this [SO-Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811919/no-signature-token-java-cxf-client). Try to alter the wsdl-binding section as suggesteed in the answer.

Comment: I've edited post to show security policy.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't modify webservice